# Unable to add and update both functionality to add the user record into Salesforce Marketing cloud Data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have created the code to add the user record to the data extension using form given below and its working fine but Its not allowing me to use add and update both functionality to update the record of existing user into data extension using the same form and same email id of the user. Its redirecting existing user to the error page.

I tried with  but its only allowing to update the record and not allowing to add.

I need both the functionality to add new user record and update existing user record to data extension into exacttarget.

```
   <form action="http://cl.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="surveyform" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="12345678">
    <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="surveyform">
    <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add">
    <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="_successURL" value="https://pub.s1.exacttarget.com/successpage">
    <input type="hidden" name="_errorURL" value="https://pub.s1.exacttarget.com/errorpage">
    <p>
        <b>Email Address: <input id="email" type="email" name="EmailID" required></b>
    </p><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitBtn">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you pleas  post your code?

Comment: Hi,

<form action="http://cl.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="surveyform" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="12345678">
            <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="survey">
            <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add">
            <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="_successURL" value="https://pub.s1.exacttarget.com/successpage">

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="_errorURL" value="https://pub.s1.exacttarget.com/errorpage">
    <p><b>Email Address: *(required)<input id="email" type="email" name="EmailID" required></b></p><br />
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submitBtn"/>

</form>

Answer (score 1):

To add the new user record and update the existing, there is a function in marketing cloud as `UPSERTDATA`. This function checks if the user exists in data extension then updates the record else add the new record.

**EXAMPLE:**
`UpsertData("SendDE",1,"FieldName1","FieldValue1","FieldName2",""FieldValue2")`

You can go through the link to know more - [upsertdata](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/upsertdata/#UpsertData) function.

**Parameter:** used in `UpsertData`

**SendDE** ->   Name of data extension from which to update specified row

**1** ->    Number of filter columns to insert or update

**Fieldname1** ->   Column name used to build the WHERE clause

**Fieldvalue1** ->  Value used to build the WHERE clause

**Fieldname2** ->   Column name used to build the INSERT clause

**fieldvalue2** ->  Value used to build the INSERT clause

let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Could you please add the exact values that i need to add it under ( ) so that i will use that tag under the form field. Please also let me know where exactly i need to add the above code within the form.

Comment: UpsertData("SendDE",1,"FieldName1","FieldValue1","FieldName2",""FieldValue2")

Comment: This requires the code be on a landing/cloud/microsite page.  It won't work with DEManager.

Comment: The landing page has created using cloud pages only.

Comment: If it's a Cloud Page, then there's no point in using DEManager.  I don't recommend SmartCapture, but using the AMPScript or SSJS functions to upsert rows is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Please let me know what values i should use to replace (SendDE, 1, Fieldname1, Fieldvalue1, Fieldname2,fieldvalue2) using AMPScript

Comment: @suhasganjare I have edited the answer, you check what exactly to pass in a parameter.